# puzzling behavior for Stringers?

Tags: go

New to Go, so please bear with me.

I've been looking at the "Tour of Go" pages, and stumbled into something puzzling about Stringers. Consider the exercise at https://tour.golang.org/methods/18

My initial answer was implementing

```
func (this *IPAddr) String() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", this[0], this[1], this[2], this[3])
}
```

however, this is not used f main prints just `fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip)`. If I change the print to `fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, ip.String())`, then it is used whether the receiver type is `*IPAddr` or `IPAddr`).

why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

Because you're passing an `IPAddr` value to `fmt.Printf`, your `String()` method isn't part of the method set. Your solution works if you pass in a pointer:

```
fmt.Printf("%v: %v\n", name, &ip)
```

But a general solution is to not use a pointer receiver:

```
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
  return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
}
```

This way the `String()` method can be used from an `IPAddr`, which is what you're passing to `Printf`, or an `*IPAddr`, which includes the methods of the value receiver.

Comment: but a non-pointer method will receive a copy of the struct, which in general is both inefficient and won't allow modifications of the original struct, right?

Comment: @RobertoAttias: The value has to be fairly large in order for the copy to be "inefficient" (depending on what you mean by that, copying 4 bytes in this case is much faster than dereferencing a pointer, not to mention it's smaller than a 64bit pointer to begin with!).  And yes, if you modify the copy of a value, the changes won't be seen in another copy. But in this case, `String()` doesn't, nor should it, modify the receiver value.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, never call method receiver `this`. It's against the [Style](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments#receiver-names).

Secondly, you've defined method on `*IPAddr`, not `IPAddr`. Do this:

```
func (ip IPAddr) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d.%d.%d.%d", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
}
```